# Fast Fourier Transform for tensor product spaces in Julia

Tags: julia, fft, physics

Right now I use the package FFTW in order to get some Fourier Transforms I am interested in. However, I'm wondering if there is already a package of FFT that can do the transformation in a vector space which is of the form `kron(C2, Rn)`, where `C2` means a 2x2 system and `Rn` represents the "spatial" subspace in which one is interested in getting the Fourier Transform. In other words, does it exist a routine that implements:

```
kron(Id2x2, FFT)[kron(C2, Rn)] = kron(C2, FFT(Rn))
```

Of course the real problem I am interested is in the "two particle case" where the vector space (Hilbert space) is `kron(kron(C2, Rn),kron(C2, Rn))`, so in this case the routine would need an operator like `kron(kron(Id2x2, FFT), kron(Id2x2, FFT))`.

Note 1: I haven't tried to do the problem taking partial traces, but in my case this option simply may not work because the states are sparse, i.e. it might be ineficient.

Note 2: Note that (unless I'm mistaken) for `kron(C2, Rn)` one could do "twice" the fft (one in each sector of `C2`). However this might also be ineficient for large vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I think you are asking. `res` is computed by FFT from  `mat = kron(C2, Rn)`, and this is (as you say) a wasteful way of doing `kron(C2, fft(Rn))` since it the FFT along the `k` dimension is re-done for each of the 2×2 other dimensions. But the point, presumably, is to do this for "entangled" states in the product space -- a generic `likemat = rand(8,2)` cannot be decomposed into factors `kron(likeC2, likeRn)`.

(If instead you are really only interested in "un-entangled" product states, then you should probably just work with their components. Combining with `kron` will then always be wasteful. The package Kronecker.jl may help for some things, but I don't think it knows about `fft`.)

This uses my package to handle `kron`-like operations; you could just write out the necessary `reshape`s yourself, too.

```
julia> C2 = [1 2; 3 4]; Rn = [1,10,0,0];

julia> mat = kron(C2,Rn)
8×2 Matrix{Int64}:
  1   2
 10  20
  0   0
  0   0
  3   4
 30  40
  0   0
  0   0

julia> using TensorCast, FFTW

# notation: kron is a reshape of a tensor product, to combine i & k

julia> kron(C2,Rn) == @cast out[(k,i),j] := C2[i,j] * Rn[k]
true

# reshape mat to put the index from Rn in its own dimension:

julia> @cast tri[k,i,j] := mat[(k,i),j]  (i in 1:2);

julia> summary(tri)
"4×2×2 Array{Int64, 3}"

# then fft(tri, 1) is the FFT along only that, reshape back:

julia> @cast res[(ktil,i),j] := fft(tri, 1)[ktil,i,j]
8×2 Matrix{ComplexF64}:
  11.0+0.0im    22.0+0.0im
   1.0-10.0im    2.0-20.0im
  -9.0+0.0im   -18.0+0.0im
   1.0+10.0im    2.0+20.0im
  33.0+0.0im    44.0+0.0im
   3.0-30.0im    4.0-40.0im
 -27.0+0.0im   -36.0+0.0im
   3.0+30.0im    4.0+40.0im

julia> res ≈ kron(C2, fft(Rn))
true

julia> res ≈ fft(mat, 1)
false

julia> fft(Rn)
4-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
 11.0 + 0.0im
  1.0 - 10.0im
 -9.0 + 0.0im
  1.0 + 10.0im

# if fft() understood the dims keyword, it could be tidier:

julia> _fft(x; dims) = fft(x, dims);

julia> @cast _res[(k,i),j] := _fft(k) mat[(k,i),j]  (i in 1:2);

julia> _res ≈ res
true
```

Comment: That's what I tought, one always need to reshape the arrays so as to get a "matrix", do the fft and then reshape back to the original form of the array, right?